# file_get_contents() failed to open stream: No such file or directory while using with php variable

Tags: php

I am using the `file_put_contents` in two scenario:

**Case 1:**

```
file_put_contents("album/$i.jpg", file_get_contents("http://www.lightscamerabollywood.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/Deepika-Padukone-movie-list-Aishwarya.jpg"));
```

in this case it working perfectly.

**Case 2:**

```
$fp = fopen('urls.txt', 'r');  
$i =1;  
while ($url = fgets($fp)) {  
file_put_contents("album/$i.jpg", file_get_contents($url));  
$i++;  
}
```

But in this case it is throwing error:

> file_get_contents() failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: In both case, its working! What is the error? is `$i` initialized?

Comment: ignore $i, error is file_get_contents() failed to open stream.

Comment: It says album directory doesn't exists

Answer (score 0):

```
$fp = fopen('urls.txt', 'r');
$i = 1;
while ($url = fgets($fp)) {
    file_put_contents("album/$i.jpg", file_get_contents(rtrim($url)));
    $i++;
}
die;
```

Comment: Hello shahrukh, i have used rtrim(), ltrim() and trim(). But it is not working for me.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.